# D3js path : add a sensibility zone

Tags: d3.js

I get a d3js path and I want to add sensibility zone to it. By sensibility zone I mean that I can select the path using the mouse pointer without beeing on that path, but very close to it (5px for exemple). Indeed, the path is one pixel width which is very annoying for the user to select it.

To enlarge this zone i had to create another path to surround the original one. I gave it opacity of zero and when hovering i change the opacity to 0.3 (bottom path in the picture below) . Everything is going fine so far, but with a thousands of lines I get proformance issues. I've implemented a virtual scroll for more perfomance but it goes more faster if I remove the sensibility zone (second path).

[image]

Anyone have an idea to replace the closed path (sensibility zone) by another thing ?

Comment: How is your line chart legible with thousands of lines on it?

Comment: I have 1500 line in 24h, users would show more than a day. Of course not at once but in chunks of 2 or 4 hours

Comment: do you keep track of **id** for each line or path, or you don't ?

Comment: @Shiko no, why ?

Comment: @bubbles I have added a suggested solution, have a look please

Comment: @bubbles if you are fetching the lines from a DB, how about you fetch the lines in the zoomed area only, to avoid fetching thousands of lines and end up with the performance issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your lines inside **symbol** tag, then use it inside SVG container using the **use** tag as below:

```
   <svg>
   <symbol id="line1">
        <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" />
    </symbol>

   <use xlink:href="#line1" x="0"  y="0"  class="line" />
   <use xlink:href="#line1" x="0"  y="0"  class="zone" />
   <svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
.line{
    stroke-width: 1px;

}
.zone{
   stroke: transparent;
    stroke-width: 5px;
}
.zone:hover{
   stroke: yellow;
    stroke-width: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But sorry your solution won't help, my lines have different shapes so I will need multiple symbols, as mutch as my lines. I will end up with the same dom elements in my actual solution. I want to remove one of the two lines (the line itself or the sensibility zone line)

Comment: @bubbles There is another way but I am not sure if it is expensive in matter of time, using nearest object on mouse move, then highlight the nearest path. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8027637

Comment: thanks, i've already tested it before, indeed it's a little bit exrpensive